# How to define a command for an interval?

Tags: errors

I am trying to define a command for a closed interval. I tried this:

> \DeclarePairedDelimiter{\closed}{\left[}{\right]}

but it does not work. I get errors like

> "Missing { inserted. \item $ \closed{a}"

Could you help me?

Comment: See also the interval package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the `\left` and `\right` bits. Just `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\closed}{[}{]}` (You don't even need to enclose the square brackets in curly brackets)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\closed}[]



\begin{document}


$\closed{a}$  $\closed[\big]{a}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works now.